# How does Django save decimal values?

Tags: python, django, decimal

What am I doing wrong?

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name=_("Name"), blank=False, null=False)
  rating = models.DecimalField(max_digits=2, decimal_places=2, default=0)
```

I do something like that:

```
average = count/len(votes) 
mymodel.rating = average
mymodel.save()
```

`count` is the sum of all ratings of given `MyModel` and votes is an array of those ratings, their division gives an average rating for MyModel (sorry if I described it incorrectly due to my poor English).

If i change previous to:

```
mymodel.name = 'anything'
mymodel.save()
```

Then 'anything' ends up in the database, but rating does not.

Why? am I using wrong field type?

Alan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

max_digits is a number of digits *before* and *after* the decimal point. With your settings it allows you to store numbers between 0.00 and 0.99. Is it right? I can not figure out the range of values for *average* variable.

Comment: Yea, if ratings can be between 0 and 5, for example, then `max_digits` needs to be 3.

Comment: Ok, that could be it. I will test this asap.

Comment: That seemed to be it :). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Models do no validation. The types you use pretty much deal with things like syncdb etc. rather than actual formatting of data, that's what a Form is for.

Comment: You know. Seven years is one year in dog years... https://stackoverflow.com/a/44904020/343215