# Restrict django FloatField to 2 decimal places

Tags: python, django, forms, model

I am looking for a way to limit the `FloatField` in Django to 2 decimal places. Has anyone got a clue of how this could be done without having to use a `DecimalField`?

I tried `decimal_places=2`, but this just gave me a migration error within the float field. So, I am thinking this method must only work within DecimalFields.

Comment: Why don't you want to use a `DecimalField`?

Comment: did u try this `models.FloatField(default=to_some_value)`

Comment: because the decimal fields add the increment and decrement arrows within the input box and i dont want that appear i have not tried the default method but will look it up and see if its right for what i need.

Comment: @AidanDoherty so, the reason is just how does it appear on the form? You know - you can change it by setting up a different widget for the field.

Comment: @alecxe So i would do that by overwriting the Decimal Field widget to changes its type value then?.

Comment: You can refer to this link for more info about Django widgets. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/

Answer (score 81, accepted):

If you are only concerned with how your `FloatField` appears in forms, you can use the template filter [`floatformat`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#floatformat).

From the Django Docs:

> If used with a numeric integer argument, floatformat rounds a number to that many decimal places.

For example, if value = 34.23234, then in your template:

```
{{ value|floatformat:2 }}  # outputs 34.23
```

Comment: Thats good but isn't completely what i am looking for but i am sure this will come in handy in the future projects thanks for your help.

Comment: This helps. I am using Postgres with Django `FloatField(default=0.00)` but its saving it as `0` by removing useless `0s` in decimal places.. which make sense.. but i want to show consistent values `0.00` or `5.43` in template... `{{ value|floatformat:2 }}` did the trick

Comment: See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23739030/restrict-django-floatfield-to-2-decimal-places/46081058#46081058) for ensuring that your data field always rounds to two decimals at the database level.

Comment: How to use this with a django ModelForm instance ?

Answer (score 23):

If you'd like to actually ensure that your model always gets saved with only two decimal places, rather than just changing the presentation of the model in a template, a custom save method on your model will work great.  The example model below shows how.

```
class MyDataModel(models.Model):
    my_float = models.FloatField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.my_float = round(self.my_float, 2)
        super(MyDataModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Now every time you save your model you will guarantee that the field will only be populated with a float of two decimal places.  This can be generalized to rounding to any number of decimal places.

Comment: this `save` method won't be executed if you call the `update` method on a queryset.

Comment: Representation is not the same thing as the actual value. By rounding the value you sacrifice precision.

Answer (score 2):

Since Django 1.8+ you can use a custom validator for FloatField/or any ModelFields:

```
def validate_decimals(value):
    try:
        return round(float(value), 2)
    except:
        raise ValidationError(
            _('%(value)s is not an integer or a float  number'),
            params={'value': value},
        )
```

...and in your model you can apply it like this:

```
from django.db import models

class MyModel(models.Model):
    even_field = models.FloatField(validators=[validate_decimals])
```

Comment: This will not work. Validators do not change the values that are being saved, they only validate that a value is acceptable.  If the value is unacceptable an exception should be raised.  This will not modify the value that is being saved.

Comment: See my answer below for an answer that will ensure a float field rounds to two decimal places.